# Xpath (Java) : Unable to locate the node or the node value

Tags: java, xpath, xml-parsing

Here is my sample code

```
   .
    .
    .
    <abc1 attrname="a_xyz_txt">
        <tab1>
            <tab2>
            .
            .
                <Update>
                    <Value>Some value</Value>
                </Update>
            .
            .
            </tab2>
        </tab1>
    </abc1>
    .
    .
    .
     <abc1 attrname="b_xyz_txt">
        <tab1>
            <tab2>
            .
            .
                <Update>
                    <Value>Some value</Value>
                </Update>
            .
            .
            </tab2>
        </tab1>
    </abc1>
    .
    .
    .
```

I have done is the following

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList nodes1 = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("//*[contains(@attrname,\"xyz\"")];

System.out.prinln("nodes Length : " + nodes1.getLength()); //Gives 2
```

until here is fine. Now I need to find the  in the xml and update the text value to "Updated Value"
How do I achieve it ?

I tried:

```
NodeList nodes2 = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("//*[contains(@attrname,\"xyz\")]//Value/text()";
 //Gives me null
```

Comment: Why not loop through the node list  and evaluate each node.

Comment: @MagdalenaFairfax I want to try with xPath. Regarding looping: I can look for the attribute name like NodeList list1 = inputXml.getElementsByTagName("abc1");, then 
create another nodelist with matching attribute name and then filter through those list to find the tag with<Value> and update the text.

Comment: XPath seems fine. Do you capture 2 nodes with : `//*[contains(@attrname,\"xyz\")]//Value` ?  You could try this alternative :`//Value[text()][ancestor::*[contains(@attrname,"xyz")]]/text()`

Comment: @E.Wiest I am getting 0 nodes with either one of them. However, NodeList nodes1 = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("//*[contains(@attrname,\"xyz\"")]; is returning 2 nodes, which is correct.

Comment: It looks "Value" elements are not found. Do the content of the first "Value" is outputed with : `string(//*[contains(@attrname,"xyz")])` ? Another option to try : `//*[contains(@attrname,"xyz")]//*[name()="Value"]/text()` Don't forget to replace "xyz" with \"xyz\" in each expression.